# Make a sum of an IEnumerable stack in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make sum by first reading the values from the terminal that the user types in. For example, first the user types 1, hits enter, types 1 again, hit enter and then he has to type + or - to make it a sum. but I can't seem to count the value that the user types in. I tried putting it in a for statement but the length of my stack is 1. [as you can see in the image I typed 2 times the numbers 5 but both are the length 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXFKM.png). So I can't use a for statement. I also tried using sum and that didn't work a swell.

Here is my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;

namespace WeekOpdr4
{
    internal class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int capacity;

            Console.WriteLine("Enter Capacity of Stack :");

            capacity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            MyStack<string> stack = new MyStack<string>(capacity + 1);

            Console.WriteLine("\ntype 'arr' to see values of stack");
            
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nEnter String to Push into Stack :");

                string temp = Console.ReadLine();

                if (temp != "+" && temp != "remove")
                {
                    int result = stack.push(temp);

                    if (result != -1)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(temp + " has been pushed into Stack !");
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The capacity has been reached !");
                    }
                }
              
                if(temp == "+")
                {               
                    string[] Elements = stack.GetAllStackElements();
                    Elements = Elements.Skip(1).ToArray();
                    Console.WriteLine("**************Stack Content **************");

                    for (int i = 0; i < Elements.Length; i++)
                    {
                        int sum = 0;
                        int sum1 = 0;
                        int sum2 = 0;
                        sum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Elements[i]) + Convert.ToInt32(Elements[i]);
                        sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(Elements[1]);
                        Console.WriteLine("summed up numbers 0: " + sum1);
                        Console.WriteLine("summed up numbers 1: " + sum2);
                    }


                    //foreach (string str in Elements)

                    //{
                    
                    //    int lenght = str.Length;
                    //    //for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
                    //    //{
                    //    //    int sum = 0;
                    //    //    sum -= Convert.ToInt32(str[i]);
                    //    //    

                    //    //}
                    //    int sum = 0;
                    //    sum =+ Convert.ToInt32(str);
                    //    Console.WriteLine("lenght: " + lenght);

                    //    Console.WriteLine("typed in numbers: " + str);

                    //   // Console.WriteLine("summed up numbers: " + sum);

                    //}
                }

                if (temp == "remove")
                {
                    stack.remove();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is my own made stack functions:

```
     using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace odpracht
{
    internal class MyStack<T>
    {
        int capacity;
        T[] stack;
        int top;

        public MyStack(int MaxElements)

        {

            capacity = MaxElements;

            stack = new T[capacity];
        }

        public int push(T Element)

        {

            if (top == capacity - 1){
                return -1;
            }
            else{
                top = top + 1;
                stack[top] = Element;
            }
            return 0;
        }

        public T pop()
        {
            T RemovedElement;
            T temp = default(T);

            //check Underflow
            if (!(top <= 0){
                RemovedElement = stack[top];
                top = top - 1;
                return RemovedElement;
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public T remove()
        {
            T temp = default(T);
            top = 0;
            return temp;
        }

        public T peek(int position)

        {
            T temp = default(T);

            //check if Position is Valid or not
            if (position < capacity && position >= 0{
                return stack[position];
            }
            return temp;
        }

        public T[] GetAllStackElements()
        {
            T[] Elements = new T[top + 1];
            Array.Copy(stack, 0, Elements, 0, top + 1);
            return Elements;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your `Console.Read` or `Console.ReadLine`  ?   (Please, code must be a [mre])

Comment: You must be getting paid by the number of lines you create, and not by the number of code lines.....    Why so many empty lines in your code ?

Comment: You didn't post enough code to produce the output listed in your image, but I can see several problems. You're initializing the `sum` values inside of the loop, so they're getting reset to `0` for every element in your stack. `Elements = Elements.Skip(1).ToArray();` removes the first element from your stack: why are you doing that? `sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(Elements[1]);` adds the second element of your stack, regardless of which element you're looking at. `sum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Elements[i]) + Convert.ToInt32(Elements[i]);` adds the same element to itself...

Comment: The best advice I can give at this point is to learn how to use the debugger to step through your code line by line, and inspect the values of your variables after each line so you can understand what's happening. Compare that with what you expect should be happening. If you run into a specific behavior you don't understand, come back and ask a question about that.

Comment: i'm skipping the first element because the first element is standard 0 and idk why thats happening, so thats why I did this @StriplingWarrior

Comment: Here's why the first element is always 0: `top = top + 1;  stack[top] = Element;` Can you tell what the problem is?

Comment: Ahh i see that I dont need top = top + 1 because of that my first value is a 0, but if i delete that section my if statement doesnt work anymore. I cant check if there is overflow or not @DStanley

Comment: how about reversing those two lines?

Comment: What is wrong with the built-in `Stack<T>` collection?

Comment: `capacity` isn't needed as you can use `stack.Length` instead.

Comment: You need to implement `internal class MyStack<T> : IEnumerable<T>` to be able to use `System.Linq.Enumerable.Sum()`

Comment: Why are you storing numbers as strings? Any why are you double counting with `sum1 = Convert.ToInt32(Elements[i]) + Convert.ToInt32(Elements[i])`

Comment: `sum2 += Convert.ToInt32(Elements[1]);` - a) that "sum2" was just initialized again to 0 (move declaration/initialization outside the loop) and b) you are using index 1 (instead of i)