# How to get a specific value from mystack<T>

Tags: c#

How could I get like the values that are pushed in first or second to the stack? is there a way to do it like in array where u do stack[0] or stack[1]? I have found a way to get every value but not how to do it for a specific field. This is my class code that gets all of the elements and this is how I call this function `string[] Elements = stack.GetAllStackElements();`:

```
       public T[] GetAllStackElements()

    {
        T[] Elements = new T[top + 1];

        Array.Copy(stack, 0, Elements, 0, top + 1);

        return Elements;

    }
```

now I need this for single values

Comment: What is `mystack`? Are you talking about the [`Stack<T>` class from System.Collections.Generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1?view=net-6.0)?

Comment: mystack is a Generic stack that I have created my self by using help from the internet @gunr2171

Comment: @hasbullah: Please focus on 1 question, make the question clear, respond to it, and then move on to you 'next' problem (others see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71666222/make-a-sum-of-an-ienumerable-stack-in-c-sharp )